ui_mainwindow.h: No such file or directory: Compile Qt with MSYS2
I want to compile a Qt-Project without an IDE like QtCreator and I use MSYS2.
I installed Qt5 with
pacman -S mingw-w64-x86_64-qt5-base

I could then already create an application with
main.cpp
#include <QApplication>
#include <QPushButton>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
 QApplication app (argc, argv);

 QPushButton button ("Hello world !");
 button.show();

 return app.exec();
}

and myproject.pro
TEMPLATE = app
TARGET = name_of_the_app

QT = core gui

greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets

SOURCES +=  main.cpp

and the commands
qmake
mingw32-make
./release/name_of_the_app.exe

However, now someone sent me a QtApplication a bit more complex and it contains mainwindow.ui and MainWindow.h
The start of those files looks like
mainwindow.h
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>MainWindow</class>
 <widget class="QMainWindow" name="MainWindow">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>1014</width>
    <height>643</height>
   </rect>

MainWindow.h
#pragma once

#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QStandardItemModel>
#include <QDate>
#include "Patient.h"
#include "MedikamentenplanAnzeigeModel.h"
#include "BehandlungenAnzeigeModel.h"

namespace Ui {
    class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

The guy, who sent me the project hasn't sent a .pro file. I want to write that myself. He has sent me a VisualStudio .sln and .vsprojx files
How do I need to adapt my project file.
I already added
HEADERS += MainWindow.h

And also
QT += widgets

but still mingw32-make can't find ui_mainwindow.h.
Of course, I am completely new to this Qt.

You need add
FORMS=mainwindow.ui

to the myproject.pro

That was correct. However, know I get the error error: 'class Ui::MainWindow' has no member named 'show'
14 |         w.show();

I think you need to run Qt's uic utility to generate C++ code like ui_mainwindow.h from mainwindow.ui.

Thanks a lot! I issued the command uci mainwindow.ui > ui_mainwindow.h , added HEADERS += ui_mainwindow.h to the .pro file, then qmake, then make and the error has disappeared. But why do I have to do this manually?

I'm not sure.  The modern way of using Qt is CMake, not QMake anyway.

Maybe you just needed to add the .UI file to SOURCES.  There must be examples somewhere.
